# reframing of polynomial equation using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to reframe a polynomial equation using MATLAB. For example I have the following polynomial equation:

758622.2445*x2+-418477.9101*x2^2+27.50552059*x1-29.66792273*x1*x2+7.993937155*x1*x2^2-0.01387653551*x1^2+0.007688875184*x1^2*x2+-458420.9152*1+9.035554275e-08*x1^3+76949.5016*x2^3=y

I want to rewrite this equation to find x1 with respect to x2 and y. Is there a way in MATLAB that I can do this?

Regards,
Vivekram

Comment: "find"? Solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with symbolic maths:

```
syms x1 x2 y
eq=758622.2445*x2+-418477.9101*x2^2+27.50552059*x1-29.66792273*x1*x2+7.993937155*x1*x2^2-0.01387653551*x1^2+0.007688875184*x1^2*x2+-458420.9152*1+9.035554275e-08*x1^3+76949.5016*x2^3-y; %note the "-y"
```

Then solve for `x1`:

```
answers=solve(eq,'x1');
```

This gives a somehow slightly impractical answer:

```
 ((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)/((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 + (((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^2 - ((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)^3)^(1/2) - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^(1/3) - (290477491679118196736*x2)/10240607678978289 + ((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 + (((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^2 - ((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)^3)^(1/2) - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^(1/3) + 524240689526195486720/10240607678978289
 524240689526195486720/10240607678978289 - ((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)/(2*((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 + (((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^2 - ((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)^3)^(1/2) - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^(1/3)) - (3^(1/2)*(((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)/((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 + (((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^2 - ((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)^3)^(1/2) - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^(1/3) - ((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 + (((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^2 - ((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)^3)^(1/2) - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^(1/3))*i)/2 - ((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 + (((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^2 - ((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)^3)^(1/2) - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^(1/3)/2 - (290477491679118196736*x2)/10240607678978289
 524240689526195486720/10240607678978289 - ((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)/(2*((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 + (((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^2 - ((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)^3)^(1/2) - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^(1/3)) + (3^(1/2)*(((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)/((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 + (((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^2 - ((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)^3)^(1/2) - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^(1/3) - ((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 + (((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^2 - ((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)^3)^(1/2) - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^(1/3))*i)/2 - ((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 + (((18889465931478580854784*y)/3413535892992763 - (14329969042344564774680920064*x2)/3413535892992763 - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^2 - ((373607477110716017672192*x2)/3413535892992763 + ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^2/9 - (100667469031835544059904*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - 1039129188224775258898432/10240607678978289)^3)^(1/2) - ((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)^3/27 + (((290477491679118196736*x2)/3413535892992763 - 524240689526195486720/3413535892992763)*((302002407095506632179712*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1120822431332148053016576*x2)/3413535892992763 + 1039129188224775258898432/3413535892992763))/6 + (7904824225910305924958912512*x2^2)/3413535892992763 - (1453534988917456608983777280*x2^3)/3413535892992763 + 8659326259947631308263391232/3413535892992763)^(1/3)/2 - (290477491679118196736*x2)/10240607678978289
```

You can try to simplify it, not really short anyway:

```
    (4096*2^(1/3)*(43239687967802394525920914526220464984948736*y - 1675946192130119618845437195925327723770746969889360*x2 + 929545073270215159552834175230731008239003999989360*x2^2 - 171853986154027941742866902559669863546308859847142*x2^3 + 2^(1/2)*(2*(464772536635107579776417087615365504119501999994680*x2^2 - 85926993077013970871433451279834931773154429923571*x2^3 - 837973096065059809422718597962663861885373484944680*x2 + 21619843983901197262960457263110232492474368*y + 503614772788955588295591518904028047560511199495004)^2 - (2422466427177787086135218358613229*x2^2 - 8734534331033532607369222830483568*x2 + 7873385733679407266674311240908036)^3)^(1/2) + 1007229545577911176591183037808056095121022398990008)^(1/3))/10240607678978289 - (290477491679118196736*x2)/10240607678978289 + (2^(2/3)*(9922422485720215904809854396879785984*x2^2 - 35776652619913349559784336713660694528*x2 + 32249387965150852164297978842759315456))/(10240607678978289*(43239687967802394525920914526220464984948736*y - 1675946192130119618845437195925327723770746969889360*x2 + 929545073270215159552834175230731008239003999989360*x2^2 - 171853986154027941742866902559669863546308859847142*x2^3 + 2^(1/2)*(2*(21619843983901197262960457263110232492474368*y - 837973096065059809422718597962663861885373484944680*x2 + 464772536635107579776417087615365504119501999994680*x2^2 - 85926993077013970871433451279834931773154429923571*x2^3 + 503614772788955588295591518904028047560511199495004)^2 - (2422466427177787086135218358613229*x2^2 - 8734534331033532607369222830483568*x2 + 7873385733679407266674311240908036)^3)^(1/2) + 1007229545577911176591183037808056095121022398990008)^(1/3)) + 524240689526195486720/10240607678978289
 524240689526195486720/10240607678978289 - (2048*2^(1/3)*(43239687967802394525920914526220464984948736*y - 1675946192130119618845437195925327723770746969889360*x2 + 929545073270215159552834175230731008239003999989360*x2^2 - 171853986154027941742866902559669863546308859847142*x2^3 + 2^(1/2)*(2*(464772536635107579776417087615365504119501999994680*x2^2 - 85926993077013970871433451279834931773154429923571*x2^3 - 837973096065059809422718597962663861885373484944680*x2 + 21619843983901197262960457263110232492474368*y + 503614772788955588295591518904028047560511199495004)^2 - (2422466427177787086135218358613229*x2^2 - 8734534331033532607369222830483568*x2 + 7873385733679407266674311240908036)^3)^(1/2) + 1007229545577911176591183037808056095121022398990008)^(1/3))/10240607678978289 - (2^(2/3)*3^(1/2)*16124693982575426082148989421379657728*i - 2^(1/3)*3^(1/2)*(43239687967802394525920914526220464984948736*y - 1675946192130119618845437195925327723770746969889360*x2 + 929545073270215159552834175230731008239003999989360*x2^2 - 171853986154027941742866902559669863546308859847142*x2^3 + 2^(1/2)*(2*(464772536635107579776417087615365504119501999994680*x2^2 - 85926993077013970871433451279834931773154429923571*x2^3 - 837973096065059809422718597962663861885373484944680*x2 + 21619843983901197262960457263110232492474368*y + 503614772788955588295591518904028047560511199495004)^2 - (2422466427177787086135218358613229*x2^2 - 8734534331033532607369222830483568*x2 + 7873385733679407266674311240908036)^3)^(1/2) + 1007229545577911176591183037808056095121022398990008)^(2/3)*2048*i - 2^(2/3)*3^(1/2)*x2*17888326309956674779892168356830347264*i + 2^(2/3)*3^(1/2)*x2^2*4961211242860107952404927198439892992*i)/(10240607678978289*(43239687967802394525920914526220464984948736*y - 1675946192130119618845437195925327723770746969889360*x2 + 929545073270215159552834175230731008239003999989360*x2^2 - 171853986154027941742866902559669863546308859847142*x2^3 + 2^(1/2)*(2*(21619843983901197262960457263110232492474368*y - 837973096065059809422718597962663861885373484944680*x2 + 464772536635107579776417087615365504119501999994680*x2^2 - 85926993077013970871433451279834931773154429923571*x2^3 + 503614772788955588295591518904028047560511199495004)^2 - (2422466427177787086135218358613229*x2^2 - 8734534331033532607369222830483568*x2 + 7873385733679407266674311240908036)^3)^(1/2) + 1007229545577911176591183037808056095121022398990008)^(1/3)) - (2^(2/3)*(4961211242860107952404927198439892992*x2^2 - 17888326309956674779892168356830347264*x2 + 16124693982575426082148989421379657728))/(10240607678978289*(43239687967802394525920914526220464984948736*y - 1675946192130119618845437195925327723770746969889360*x2 + 929545073270215159552834175230731008239003999989360*x2^2 - 171853986154027941742866902559669863546308859847142*x2^3 + 2^(1/2)*(2*(21619843983901197262960457263110232492474368*y - 837973096065059809422718597962663861885373484944680*x2 + 464772536635107579776417087615365504119501999994680*x2^2 - 85926993077013970871433451279834931773154429923571*x2^3 + 503614772788955588295591518904028047560511199495004)^2 - (2422466427177787086135218358613229*x2^2 - 8734534331033532607369222830483568*x2 + 7873385733679407266674311240908036)^3)^(1/2) + 1007229545577911176591183037808056095121022398990008)^(1/3)) - (290477491679118196736*x2)/10240607678978289
 524240689526195486720/10240607678978289 - (2048*2^(1/3)*(43239687967802394525920914526220464984948736*y - 1675946192130119618845437195925327723770746969889360*x2 + 929545073270215159552834175230731008239003999989360*x2^2 - 171853986154027941742866902559669863546308859847142*x2^3 + 2^(1/2)*(2*(464772536635107579776417087615365504119501999994680*x2^2 - 85926993077013970871433451279834931773154429923571*x2^3 - 837973096065059809422718597962663861885373484944680*x2 + 21619843983901197262960457263110232492474368*y + 503614772788955588295591518904028047560511199495004)^2 - (2422466427177787086135218358613229*x2^2 - 8734534331033532607369222830483568*x2 + 7873385733679407266674311240908036)^3)^(1/2) + 1007229545577911176591183037808056095121022398990008)^(1/3))/10240607678978289 + (2^(2/3)*3^(1/2)*16124693982575426082148989421379657728*i - 2^(1/3)*3^(1/2)*(43239687967802394525920914526220464984948736*y - 1675946192130119618845437195925327723770746969889360*x2 + 929545073270215159552834175230731008239003999989360*x2^2 - 171853986154027941742866902559669863546308859847142*x2^3 + 2^(1/2)*(2*(464772536635107579776417087615365504119501999994680*x2^2 - 85926993077013970871433451279834931773154429923571*x2^3 - 837973096065059809422718597962663861885373484944680*x2 + 21619843983901197262960457263110232492474368*y + 503614772788955588295591518904028047560511199495004)^2 - (2422466427177787086135218358613229*x2^2 - 8734534331033532607369222830483568*x2 + 7873385733679407266674311240908036)^3)^(1/2) + 1007229545577911176591183037808056095121022398990008)^(2/3)*2048*i - 2^(2/3)*3^(1/2)*x2*17888326309956674779892168356830347264*i + 2^(2/3)*3^(1/2)*x2^2*4961211242860107952404927198439892992*i)/(10240607678978289*(43239687967802394525920914526220464984948736*y - 1675946192130119618845437195925327723770746969889360*x2 + 929545073270215159552834175230731008239003999989360*x2^2 - 171853986154027941742866902559669863546308859847142*x2^3 + 2^(1/2)*(2*(21619843983901197262960457263110232492474368*y - 837973096065059809422718597962663861885373484944680*x2 + 464772536635107579776417087615365504119501999994680*x2^2 - 85926993077013970871433451279834931773154429923571*x2^3 + 503614772788955588295591518904028047560511199495004)^2 - (2422466427177787086135218358613229*x2^2 - 8734534331033532607369222830483568*x2 + 7873385733679407266674311240908036)^3)^(1/2) + 1007229545577911176591183037808056095121022398990008)^(1/3)) - (2^(2/3)*(4961211242860107952404927198439892992*x2^2 - 17888326309956674779892168356830347264*x2 + 16124693982575426082148989421379657728))/(10240607678978289*(43239687967802394525920914526220464984948736*y - 1675946192130119618845437195925327723770746969889360*x2 + 929545073270215159552834175230731008239003999989360*x2^2 - 171853986154027941742866902559669863546308859847142*x2^3 + 2^(1/2)*(2*(21619843983901197262960457263110232492474368*y - 837973096065059809422718597962663861885373484944680*x2 + 464772536635107579776417087615365504119501999994680*x2^2 - 85926993077013970871433451279834931773154429923571*x2^3 + 503614772788955588295591518904028047560511199495004)^2 - (2422466427177787086135218358613229*x2^2 - 8734534331033532607369222830483568*x2 + 7873385733679407266674311240908036)^3)^(1/2) + 1007229545577911176591183037808056095121022398990008)^(1/3)) - (290477491679118196736*x2)/10240607678978289
```